# SQL Server Agent Job - Adding AD Group to Notification Drop Down

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to add notifications when an agent job fails and I need to know how to add an active directory group to the notification drop down.

[image: Agent Notification Page]

Comment: You'll need to create an operator (if you haven't done so already): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/ms186747(v=sql.110).aspx  The email address of the operator would correspond to a distribution list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are defined as Operators.

Here's a good link: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1523/how-to-setup-sql-server-alerts-and-email-operator-notifications/ showing how to add them.